# DataTables: re-render table dynamically with new data?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net) v1.10.15 as part of a single-page JavaScript application, and would like to update the table with new data (loaded via Ajax) when the user changes a dropdown.

This is my code:

```
 custname.on("change", function(e) {
        $('#titles').DataTable().rows().invalidate('data');
        $('#titles').DataTable({
            "ajax":{
              "url": "data/" + e.added.slug + ".geojson",
              "dataSrc": "features"
            },
            "columns": [
              { data: "properties.name" },
              { data: "properties.address" }
            ],
            "deferRender": true
        });
        $('#titles').DataTable().draw();
});
```

But the table always shows `No data available in table`.

The same code works fine if I just call the `$('#titles').DataTable({...` line immediately on page load, with a specified GeoJSON file, so I know the problem isn't anything to do with the Ajax or column loading.

How can I fix this?

I'm wondering if perhaps I need to totally empty the HTML element and re-create it each time.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve the problem? If not how can I improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) the correct way to do this would be something like:

```
custname.on("change", function(e) {
    $("#titles")ajax.url("data/" + e.added.slug + ".geojson").load();
});
```

Hope this helps :)